# Send selected value of two dropdown to PHP script without Submit using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two dropdown list, I want to know what user has selected in these dropdowns, based on that I need fetch data from DB using PHP. Please note that There is no submit button. I don't know how send javascript var value to PHP code.

Here it is what I've done so far

```
 <head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('select.day').on('change',function(){     
        var select = $(this).val();         
        alert(select);          

        });

        $.ajax({

            Type : "POST",              
            url : "new.php",
            data : {name : select},     
            success : function(msg)
            {
                $('#d').text(msg);      
                alert(msg);
            }   
        }); 
    });

</script>
</head>
   <body>
<p id="d"></p>
<Select class="day" onchange="getTimeFrame(this.value)">
        <Option >Today</Option>
        <Option>This Week</Option>
    <Option>Last Week</Option> 
    </Select>

    <Select class="filter" onchange="getFilterType(this.value)">
        <Option >User</Option>
        <Option>Client</Option>
    <Option>Project</Option>
    </Select>
</body>
</html>
```

Here it is PHP file

```
<?php

    // $time = $_POST['select'];         
     $filter = $_POST['name'];     
     //echo "Hello from new";      
     echo $filter;

?>
```

But nothing seems working for me. Anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your `Ajax` code inside the `onchange` event of the select .

**Updated**

**typo** change `type` instead `Type` ,is not caps .All are small letter.Javascript is case sensitive

```
$('select.day').on('change', function() {
    var select = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "new.php",
    data: {
      name: select
    },
    success: function(msg) {
      $('#d').text(msg);
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
  })
```

Change Html as like this

```
<Select class="day">
        <Option >Today</Option>
        <Option>This Week</Option>
    <Option>Last Week</Option> 
    </Select>
```

***For send both drop down value try this***

```js
$('select.day').on('change', function() {
   var select =  $('select.day').map(function(){
    return $(this).val()
    }).get();
    console.log(select)
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "new.php",
    data: {
      name: select
    },
    success: function(msg) {
      $('#d').text(msg);
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select class="day" >
        <Option >Today</Option>
        <Option>This Week</Option>
    <Option>Last Week</Option> 
    </Select>

    <Select class="day filter" >
        <Option >User</Option>
        <Option>Client</Option>
    <Option>Project</Option>
    </Select>
```

Comment: Thanks. It showing me an alert but blank one. Am I doing something wrong while sending parameter?

Comment: didn't help it.

Comment: No need to change php .its just a typo change  `type` instead `Type` ,is not caps .All are small letter.Javascript is case sensitive

Comment: Thanks. $_REQUEST['name'] working instead of $_POST['name']. Parameter is reaching to PHP page. But Now how send both dropdown selected value together?

Comment: @KiranKoravi no need change the `$_REQUEST['name']` do with  `$_POST['name']` is enough  .Just fix the typo in your js .see my updated answer .

Comment: Yes. Thanks.But How to send both dropdown selected item to PHP script?

Comment: @KiranKoravi see my updated answer i was added with working snippet do like this .create the array  passing to the php

Answer (score 0):

In your onchange Event you only get with select = $(this)... the value of the changed selectbox. You have to reference to the other one, too with Name = $(".filter")..... and then send it with ajax